# PyInstaller not correctly importing pycrypto... sometimes

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyinstaller, pycrypto

I'm packaging a project with PyInstaller on different ubuntu machines.
On some of them, when executing the generated project, it throws this error:

> File
>   "~/PyInstaller-2.1/proj/build/proj/out00-PYZ.pyz/Crypto.Random",
>   line 28, in  ImportError: cannot import name OSRNG

However the import works perfectly ok in python console and I can execute the project without packaging it.

I've tried uninstalling and reinstalling pycrypto without success, I've also tried adding a specific

> from Crypto.Random import OSRNG

to the main file just so PyInstaller would pick it up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've solved it by adding Crypto directory tree to spec file

I get the path with this function:

```
def get_crypto_path():
    '''Auto import sometimes fails on linux'''
    import Crypto
    crypto_path = Crypto.__path__[0]
    return crypto_path
```

And then substitute in spec file:

```
dict_tree = Tree('CRYPTO_PATH', prefix='Crypto', excludes=["*.pyc"])
a.datas += dict_tree
```

Answer (score 3):

I was able to solve the problem with hithwen's recipe, but with a slightly different `.spec` file. I'll leave it here for reference for everyone.

```
# -*- mode: python -*-

#Tweaks to properly import pyCrypto

#Get the path
def get_crypto_path():
    '''Auto import sometimes fails on linux'''
    import Crypto
    crypto_path = Crypto.__path__[0]
    return crypto_path

#Analysis remains untouched
a = Analysis(['myapp.py'],
             pathex=[],
             hiddenimports=[],
             hookspath=None,
             runtime_hooks=None)
#Add to the tree the pyCrypto folder
dict_tree = Tree(get_crypto_path(), prefix='Crypto', excludes=["*.pyc"])
a.datas += dict_tree
#As we have the so/pyd in the pyCrypto folder, we don't need them anymore, so we take them out from the executable path
a.binaries = filter(lambda x: 'Crypto' not in x[0], a.binaries)
#PYZ remains untouched
pyz = PYZ(a.pure)
#EXE remains untouched
exe = EXE(pyz,
          a.scripts,
          exclude_binaries=True,
          name='myapp',
          debug=False,
          strip=None,
          upx=True,
          console=True )
#COLLECT remains untouched
coll = COLLECT(exe,
               a.binaries,
               a.zipfiles,
               a.datas,
               strip=None,
               upx=True,
               name='myapp')
```

Answer (score 0):

I got it working by replacing pycrypto / pycryptodome with `pycryptodomex`. Sharing a link to the already posted answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50009769/4355695