# PyInstaller and Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, pyinstaller

I have a fairly simple Python module that I am trying to compile into a Windows .exe file.  In my script I am using the wxPython and Pandas libraries.  The PyInstaller .exe file that is generated *only* works/opens when the Pandas library is excluded from my module.

I am getting the same issue whether I use `--onefile` or `--onedir` in PyInstaller.  I found online that the "new" version of PyInstaller (2.1) should have taken care of this bug.  Does anyone have any ideas on what to do?

```
PyInstaller: version 2.1
pandas: version 0.15.2
Python: version 2.7
```

Comment: My post was delete by [ChrisF♦](https://stackoverflow.com/users/59303/chrisf) , hope this link helps anyone in search of answer for this in detail [Pyinstaller created exe file can not load a keras nn model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45830206/pyinstaller-created-exe-file-can-not-load-a-keras-nn-model#answer-45842864)

Answer (score 22):

I ran into the same issue.  I boiled it down to a simple script like this Hello.py:

```
import pandas
print "hello world, pandas was imported successfully!"
```

To get pandas to import at run-time correctly I had to modify the Hello.spec to the following:

```
# -*- mode: python -*-

block_cipher = None

def get_pandas_path():
    import pandas
    pandas_path = pandas.__path__[0]
    return pandas_path

a = Analysis(['Hello.py'],
         pathex=['C:\\ScriptsThatRequirePandas'],
         binaries=None,
         datas=None,
         hiddenimports=[],
         hookspath=None,
         runtime_hooks=None,
         excludes=None,
         win_no_prefer_redirects=None,
         win_private_assemblies=None,
         cipher=block_cipher)

dict_tree = Tree(get_pandas_path(), prefix='pandas', excludes=["*.pyc"])
a.datas += dict_tree
a.binaries = filter(lambda x: 'pandas' not in x[0], a.binaries)

pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data,
         cipher=block_cipher)
exe = EXE(pyz,
      a.scripts,
      exclude_binaries=True,
      name='Hello',
      debug=False,
      strip=None,
      upx=True,
      console=True )
scoll = COLLECT(exe,
           a.binaries,
           a.zipfiles,
           a.datas,
           strip=None,
           upx=True,
           name='Hello')
```

I then ran:

```
$pyinstaller Hello.spec --onefile
```

from the command prompt and got the 'hello world' message I expected.  I still don't completely understand why this is necessary.  I have a custom build of pandas - which is hooked into the MKL libraries - but it isn't clear to me that this is causing the run failure.

This is similar to the answer here: [Pyinstaller not correclty importing pycripto... sometimes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23289047/pyinstaller-not-correclty-importing-pycripto-sometimes)

Comment: @ physicistintheory --  After using your suggestion, my program worked great for me with console=True, but it is not working when the console=False. But, when I say True I get the black command window at the end along with my wanted exe window which is not required. When I try deleting the black window my desired window also get closed. Can you please suggest me!

Comment: what is Tree in this context?

Answer (score 14):

I had a similar issue with pyinstaller version 3.3. The solution was that there was a missing hiddenimport hook as described [here](https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/issues/2978)

I created a new file under Pyinstaller/hooks/ called hook-pandas.py and put the content as described in this commit [here](https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/pull/2998/files) and reinstalled pyinstaller manually via python setup.py install in the Pyinstaller directory.

The issue did not recur when I created exe from my pandas script with pyinstaller using the --onefile option.

Comment: This worked for me, though I didn't have to reinstall Pyinstaller.

Comment: This answer simplifies it all to a bunch of command lines : https://stackoverflow.com/a/48846546/4355695

Answer (score 5):

Just as another solution, adding `--hidden-import=pandas._libs.tslibs.timedelta` or whatever the module is missing to the `pyinstaller` command also works.

This may be helpful if you don't want to touch the source of pyinstaller.

Answer (score 3):

I had exactly the same problem, and I found another solution (the only one that worked for me actually) :

I followed pretty much this : https://medium.com/@liron92/pyinstaller-with-pandas-problems-solutions-and-workflow-with-code-examples-c72973e1e23f

Except for the fact that I run my virtual environnement on Anaconda.

## Quick step-by-step sollution

Before I start : these are the steps that I followed for my particuliar case, you might want to adapt a little bit depending on your situation.

#### 1) Create and configure your virtual environnement

I used Anaconda to create my env :

```
conda create --name myenv
```

Then I installed all the module I needed :

```
conda install -n myenv pandas
conda install -n myenv -c conda-forge python-docx
etc.
```

#### 2) Activate your environnement and switch to project path

On Anaconda Prompt :

```
conda activate myenv
cd path/to/your/project/folder
```

#### 3) Create and modify your *.spec file

Still on the same Anaconda Prompt window :

```
pyi-makespec project.py
```

Then open your project.spec file, it will looks like that:

```
# -*- mode: python ; coding: utf-8 -*-

block_cipher = None


a = Analysis(['project.py'],
             pathex=['path/to/your/project/folder'],
             binaries=[],
             datas=[],
             hiddenimports=[],
             hookspath=[],
             runtime_hooks=[],
             excludes=[],
             win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
             win_private_assemblies=False,
             cipher=block_cipher,
             noarchive=False)
pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data,
             cipher=block_cipher)
exe = EXE(pyz,
          a.scripts,
          [],
          exclude_binaries=True,
          name='main',
          debug=False,
          bootloader_ignore_signals=False,
          strip=False,
          upx=True,
          console=False )
coll = COLLECT(exe,
               a.binaries,
               a.zipfiles,
               a.datas,
               strip=False,
               upx=True,
               upx_exclude=[],
               name='main')
```

You just modify `hiddenimports = []` and add all the implicit import (which include pandas).
In my case, I was also using Tkinter, so I specified :

```
hiddenimports=['pandas', 'tkinter']
```

#### 4) Finally run pyinstaller

On the same Anaconda Prompt window (environnement activated, on your project directory) :

```
pyinstaller main.spec
```

And then you're done !

### Disclaimer

I see everywhere people telling you that you should use `--onefile` when you compile a Python project with Pyinstaller, I honestly think you shouldn't : it makes the *.exe way slower. Maybe I'm missing something with this so please if you use it explain to me.

## Specs

```
Windows 10
Anaconda 4.8.2
Python 3.7.6
Pandas 1.0.5
```

Answer (score 1):

### For anyone looking to convert Python scripts with pandas involved to exe in 2021

I struggled a lot with [pyinstaller](https://www.pyinstaller.org/) but got perfect results with [Nuitka](https://nuitka.net/). Perks:

- low file size (500kB)
- quick build and execution time (similar to Python execution time)
- and best of all: **pandas support out-of-the-box** without virtual envs!

Just install nuitka

`pip install nuitka`

and build the exe

`nuitka hello.py`

**You can even use upx afterwards to compress further!**

`upx hello.exe`

In my case reduced file size to 1/3, just ~150kB `.exe` file size for a simple pandas script reading and saving an excel-file.

**See my [blog post](https://geo.rocks/post/python-to-exe/) for further details.**

Answer (score 1):

if anyone here is using **python 3.10** :

you will probably encounter **"IndexError: tuple index out of range"** error.

to fix it:

**I found a solution to this problem.**
This is a python 3.10 bug, and after applying the fix everything related to pyinstaller started working properly.

"
so basically you have to go to the folder "Python310\Lib" and edit the file 'dis.py'.
In the 'dis.py' file you have to find this "def _unpack_opargs" and inside the else statement write a new line with this: "extended_arg = 0".

I did something like that:

```
    else:
        arg = None
        extended_arg = 0 
    yield (i, op, arg)
```

and everything is working fine now.
"
https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/issues/6301#issuecomment-974927257

Answer (score 0):

I solved the same problem by using a hook file in the project directory (per pyinstaller document), hook-pandas.py

```
hiddenimports = [
    'pandas._libs.tslibs.timedeltas',
    'pandas._libs.tslibs.nattype',
    'pandas._libs.tslibs.np_datetime',
    'pandas._libs.skiplist',
]
```

then adding one line in the spec file:

```
...
a = Analysis([...
hookspath=['.'],
...],
...
```

I tried to include `hiddenimports=[..., 'pandas', ...]` in the spec file, somehow that didn't work out as expected.

Answer (score 0):

With python version=3.8 and pyinstaller=3.6, no need to custom the pyinstaller or add pandas hook, the hook-pandas.py already exists in Lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\hooks and everything works fine.

Comment: Did not work for me when the .exe was created on Windows 7 but I tried running it on Windows 10. Pyinstaller 3.6, Python 3.8.2

Comment: Do not work for me with python 3.8.3 and pyinstaller 3.6

Answer (score 0):

This issue has been solved in pyinstaller 4.10

Answer (score 0):

My solution found in 2023 March:

**ADD `pyinstaller` to the `.venv` package list**

Background:

```
Environment:
    MacOS Ventura (13.2.1)
    Developed in PyCharm @022.3.2 (Professional Edition) 
    Using pipenv version 2023.2.18 (brew installation)
    pandas 1.5.3
    pyinstaller 5.9.0
```

The solution I found was to make SURE I had installed `pyinstaller` as a package into Pycharm's  **Settings/Project/Python Interpreter/package list** --- added `pyinstaller`

And now everything WORKS fine.