# PyInstaller and Pandas error: pyi_rth_qt4plugins returned -1

Tags: python-2.7, pandas, pyinstaller

I've been trying to compile a python script into an exe with pyinstaller but I keep getting an error after running the exe file:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 43, in <module>
  File "c:\users\martin~1\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-arzhlv\pyinstaller\PyInst
aller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 546, in load_module
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified procedure could not be found.
pyi_rth_qt4plugins returned -1
```

I commented out my whole script so I only have this in my GetMBEPressure.py script:

```
from pandas import DataFrame as df
print("this is a test!")
```

I compile it with:

```
pyinstaller.exe -F --debug --clean GetMBEPressure.spec
```

My spec file looks like:

```
# -*- mode: python -*-

block_cipher = None


a = Analysis(['GetMBEPressure.py'],
             pathex=['C:\\Users\\Public\\MBELogAnalysis'],
             binaries=None,
             datas=None,
             hiddenimports=['_socket'],
             hookspath=[],
             runtime_hooks=[],
             excludes=[],
             win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
             win_private_assemblies=False,
             cipher=block_cipher)
pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data,
             cipher=block_cipher)
exe = EXE(pyz,
          a.scripts,
          a.binaries,
          a.zipfiles,
          a.datas,
          name='GetMBEPressure',
          debug=True,
          strip=False,
          upx=True,
          console=True )
```

While it is building it outputs:

```
53 INFO: PyInstaller: 3.1.1
53 INFO: Python: 2.7.10
55 INFO: Platform: Windows-7-6.1.7601-SP1
55 INFO: wrote C:\Users\Public\MBELogAnalysis\GetMBEPressure.spec
55 INFO: UPX is not available.
56 INFO: Removing temporary files and cleaning cache in C:\Users\Martin\AppData\Roaming\pyinstaller
59 INFO: Extending PYTHONPATH with paths
['C:\\Users\\Public\\MBELogAnalysis', 'C:\\Users\\Public\\MBELogAnalysis']
59 INFO: checking Analysis
59 INFO: Building Analysis because out00-Analysis.toc is non existent
59 INFO: Initializing module dependency graph...
65 INFO: Initializing module graph hooks...
215 INFO: running Analysis out00-Analysis.toc
220 INFO: Adding Microsoft.VC90.CRT to dependent assemblies of final executable
  required by c:\python27\python.exe
319 INFO: Found C:\Windows\WinSxS\Manifests\x86_policy.9.0.microsoft.vc90.crt_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_9.0.21022.8_none_60a5df56e60dc5df.manifest
322 INFO: Found C:\Windows\WinSxS\Manifests\x86_policy.9.0.microsoft.vc90.crt_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_9.0.30729.1_none_8550c6b5d18a9128.manifest
322 INFO: Found C:\Windows\WinSxS\Manifests\x86_policy.9.0.microsoft.vc90.crt_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_9.0.30729.4926_none_f47c47b2f658b4a8.manifest
323 INFO: Found C:\Windows\WinSxS\Manifests\x86_policy.9.0.microsoft.vc90.crt_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_9.0.30729.4940_none_f47ed0f6f6564d90.manifest
325 INFO: Found C:\Windows\WinSxS\Manifests\x86_policy.9.0.microsoft.vc90.crt_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_9.0.30729.6161_none_f480bfaef65491a5.manifest
425 INFO: Searching for assembly x86_Microsoft.VC90.CRT_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_9.0.30729.6161_none ...
427 INFO: Found manifest C:\Windows\WinSxS\Manifests\x86_microsoft.vc90.crt_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_9.0.30729.6161_none_50934f2ebcb7eb57.manifest
427 INFO: Searching for file msvcr90.dll
427 INFO: Found file C:\Windows\WinSxS\x86_microsoft.vc90.crt_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_9.0.30729.6161_none_50934f2ebcb7eb57\msvcr90.dll
427 INFO: Searching for file msvcp90.dll
427 INFO: Found file C:\Windows\WinSxS\x86_microsoft.vc90.crt_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_9.0.30729.6161_none_50934f2ebcb7eb57\msvcp90.dll
427 INFO: Searching for file msvcm90.dll
427 INFO: Found file C:\Windows\WinSxS\x86_microsoft.vc90.crt_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_9.0.30729.6161_none_50934f2ebcb7eb57\msvcm90.dll
527 INFO: Found C:\Windows\WinSxS\Manifests\x86_policy.9.0.microsoft.vc90.crt_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_9.0.21022.8_none_60a5df56e60dc5df.manifest
527 INFO: Found C:\Windows\WinSxS\Manifests\x86_policy.9.0.microsoft.vc90.crt_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_9.0.30729.1_none_8550c6b5d18a9128.manifest
529 INFO: Found C:\Windows\WinSxS\Manifests\x86_policy.9.0.microsoft.vc90.crt_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_9.0.30729.4926_none_f47c47b2f658b4a8.manifest
529 INFO: Found C:\Windows\WinSxS\Manifests\x86_policy.9.0.microsoft.vc90.crt_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_9.0.30729.4940_none_f47ed0f6f6564d90.manifest
529 INFO: Found C:\Windows\WinSxS\Manifests\x86_policy.9.0.microsoft.vc90.crt_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_9.0.30729.6161_none_f480bfaef65491a5.manifest
530 INFO: Adding redirect Microsoft.VC90.CRT version (9, 0, 21022, 8) -> (9, 0, 30729, 6161)
595 INFO: Analyzing C:\Users\Public\MBELogAnalysis\GetMBEPressure.py
2213 INFO: Processing pre-safe import module hook   _xmlplus
6188 INFO: Processing pre-safe import module hook   six.moves
7056 INFO: Processing pre-find module path hook   distutils
11687 INFO: Processing pre-find module path hook   site
11688 INFO: site: retargeting to fake-dir 'c:\\python27\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\fake-modules'
11717 INFO: Processing pre-safe import module hook   win32com
76519 INFO: Looking for import hooks ...
76523 INFO: Processing hook   hook-distutils.py
76523 INFO: Processing hook   hook-OpenGL.py
76865 INFO: Processing hook   hook-sysconfig.py
76865 INFO: Processing hook   hook-OpenGL_accelerate.py
76866 INFO: Processing hook   hook-xml.py
76866 INFO: Processing hook   hook-PIL.py
76878 INFO: Excluding import 'FixTk'
76888 INFO: Excluding import 'Tkinter'
76898 INFO: Excluding import 'PyQt5'
76907 INFO: Excluding import 'PySide'
76917 INFO: Excluding import 'PyQt4'
76925 INFO: Processing hook   hook-gtk.py
76927 WARNING: Hidden import 'gtkglext' not found (probably old hook)
76930 WARNING: Hidden import 'gdkgl' not found (probably old hook)
76930 WARNING: Hidden import 'gdkglext' not found (probably old hook)
76931 WARNING: Hidden import 'gtk.gdk' not found (probably old hook)
76931 WARNING: Hidden import 'gtk.gtkgl' not found (probably old hook)
76931 WARNING: Hidden import 'gtk.gtkgl._gtkgl' not found (probably old hook)
76934 WARNING: Hidden import 'gtkgl' not found (probably old hook)
77198 INFO: Processing hook   hook-scipy.sparse.csgraph.py
77202 INFO: Processing hook   hook-zmq.py
77514 INFO: Excluding import 'zmq.libzmq'
77523 WARNING:   From zmq removing import zmq.libzmq
77524 INFO: Processing hook   hook-pycparser.py
77746 INFO: Processing hook   hook-scipy.io.matlab.py
77746 INFO: Processing hook   hook-jinja2.py
77763 INFO: Processing hook   hook-lxml.etree.py
77771 INFO: Processing hook   hook-httplib.py
77773 INFO: Processing hook   hook-tables.py
77773 INFO: Processing hook   hook-pydoc.py
77782 INFO: Excluding import 'Tkinter'
77789 WARNING:   From pydoc removing import Tkinter
77789 INFO: Processing hook   hook-pygments.py
79154 INFO: Processing hook   hook-PyQt4.py
79155 INFO: Processing hook   hook-jsonschema.py
79159 INFO: Processing hook   hook-_tkinter.py
79271 INFO: checking Tree
79271 INFO: Building Tree because out00-Tree.toc is non existent
79271 INFO: Building Tree out00-Tree.toc
79514 INFO: checking Tree
79516 INFO: Building Tree because out01-Tree.toc is non existent
79516 INFO: Building Tree out01-Tree.toc
79542 INFO: Processing hook   hook-docutils.py
80394 INFO: Processing hook   hook-matplotlib.backends.py
82099 INFO:   Matplotlib backend "GTK": ignored
    No module named _backend_gdk
83605 INFO:   Matplotlib backend "GTKAgg": ignored
    No module named _backend_gdk
85085 INFO:   Matplotlib backend "GTKCairo": ignored
    No module named _backend_gdk
86481 INFO:   Matplotlib backend "MacOSX": ignored
    cannot import name _macosx
87922 INFO:   Matplotlib backend "Qt4Agg": added
89352 INFO:   Matplotlib backend "Qt5Agg": added
90759 INFO:   Matplotlib backend "TkAgg": added
92276 INFO:   Matplotlib backend "WX": added
93832 INFO:   Matplotlib backend "WXAgg": added
94063 INFO:   Matplotlib backend "GTK3Cairo": ignored
    Gtk3 backend requires pygobject to be installed.
95471 INFO:   Matplotlib backend "GTK3Agg": ignored
    Gtk3 backend requires pygobject to be installed.
c:\python27\lib\site-packages\IPython\kernel\__init__.py:13: ShimWarning: The `IPython.kernel` package has been deprecated. You should import from ipykernel or jupyter_client instead.
  "You should import from ipykernel or jupyter_client instead.", ShimWarning)
98098 INFO:   Matplotlib backend "WebAgg": added
c:\python27\lib\site-packages\IPython\kernel\__init__.py:13: ShimWarning: The `IPython.kernel` package has been deprecated. You should import from ipykernel or jupyter_client instead.
  "You should import from ipykernel or jupyter_client instead.", ShimWarning)
100317 INFO:   Matplotlib backend "nbAgg": added
101774 INFO:   Matplotlib backend "agg": added
103197 INFO:   Matplotlib backend "cairo": added
103395 INFO:   Matplotlib backend "emf": ignored
    No module named backend_emf
104881 INFO:   Matplotlib backend "gdk": ignored
    No module named _backend_gdk
106296 INFO:   Matplotlib backend "pdf": added
107957 INFO:   Matplotlib backend "pgf": added
109375 INFO:   Matplotlib backend "ps": added
110783 INFO:   Matplotlib backend "svg": added
112191 INFO:   Matplotlib backend "template": added
112608 INFO: Processing hook   hook-PIL.Image.py
112909 INFO: Processing hook   hook-matplotlib.py
113111 INFO: Processing hook   hook-xml.dom.domreg.py
113112 INFO: Processing hook   hook-PyQt4.QtGui.py
113388 INFO: Processing hook   hook-pkg_resources.py
113792 INFO: Processing hook   hook-requests.py
113796 INFO: Processing hook   hook-scipy.linalg.py
113796 WARNING: Hidden import 'scipy.linalg.cython_blas' not found (probably old hook)
113797 WARNING: Hidden import 'scipy.linalg.cython_lapack' not found (probably old hook)
113797 INFO: Processing hook   hook-IPython.py
116625 INFO: Processing hook   hook-certifi.py
116628 INFO: Processing hook   hook-pytz.py
116700 INFO: Processing hook   hook-pywintypes.py
117264 INFO: Processing hook   hook-setuptools.py
117264 INFO: Processing hook   hook-PIL.SpiderImagePlugin.py
117274 INFO: Excluding import 'FixTk'
117282 INFO: Excluding import 'Tkinter'
117290 INFO: Processing hook   hook-encodings.py
117628 INFO: Processing hook   hook-sqlalchemy.py
117792 WARNING: Hidden import 'MySQLdb' not found (probably old hook)
117794 WARNING: Hidden import 'psycopg2' not found (probably old hook)
119279 INFO: Processing hook   hook-PyQt4.QtSvg.py
119282 INFO: Processing hook   hook-xml.etree.cElementTree.py
119282 INFO: Processing hook   hook-babel.py
119362 INFO: Processing hook   hook-patsy.py
119363 INFO: Processing hook   hook-sqlite3.py
119368 INFO: Processing hook   hook-PyQt4.QtCore.py
119425 INFO: Processing hook   hook-scipy.special._ufuncs.py
119427 INFO: Processing hook   hook-sphinx.py
125000 INFO: Processing hook   hook-idlelib.py
125013 INFO: Processing hook   hook-win32com.py
125172 INFO: Processing hook   hook-pythoncom.py
125960 INFO: Looking for ctypes DLLs
126246 INFO: Analyzing run-time hooks ...
126256 WARNING: Attempted to add Python module twice with different upper/lowercases: tkFileDialog
126256 WARNING: Attempted to add Python module twice with different upper/lowercases: tkMessageBox
126256 WARNING: Attempted to add Python module twice with different upper/lowercases: FileDialog
126257 WARNING: Attempted to add Python module twice with different upper/lowercases: Tkinter
126257 WARNING: Attempted to add Python module twice with different upper/lowercases: ConfigParser
126257 WARNING: Attempted to add Python module twice with different upper/lowercases: Queue
126257 WARNING: Attempted to add Python module twice with different upper/lowercases: UserString
126257 WARNING: Attempted to add Python module twice with different upper/lowercases: cStringIO
126257 WARNING: Attempted to add Python module twice with different upper/lowercases: cPickle
126257 WARNING: Attempted to add Python module twice with different upper/lowercases: StringIO
126284 WARNING: Attempted to add Python module twice with different upper/lowercases: HTMLParser
126297 INFO: Including run-time hook 'pyi_rth_pkgres.py'
126299 INFO: Including run-time hook 'pyi_rth__tkinter.py'
126300 INFO: Including run-time hook 'pyi_rth_qt4plugins.py'
126302 INFO: Including run-time hook 'pyi_rth_win32comgenpy.py'
126303 INFO: Including run-time hook 'pyi_rth_mplconfig.py'
126305 INFO: Including run-time hook 'pyi_rth_mpldata.py'
126415 INFO: Looking for dynamic libraries
126869 INFO: Found C:\Windows\WinSxS\Manifests\x86_policy.9.0.microsoft.vc90.mfc_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_9.0.21022.8_none_5926f98ceadc42c2.manifest
126869 INFO: Found C:\Windows\WinSxS\Manifests\x86_policy.9.0.microsoft.vc90.mfc_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_9.0.30729.1_none_7dd1e0ebd6590e0b.manifest
126871 INFO: Found C:\Windows\WinSxS\Manifests\x86_policy.9.0.microsoft.vc90.mfc_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_9.0.30729.6161_none_ed01d9e4fb230e88.manifest
126970 INFO: Searching for assembly x86_Microsoft.VC90.MFC_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_9.0.30729.6161_none ...
126970 INFO: Found manifest C:\Windows\WinSxS\Manifests\x86_microsoft.vc90.mfc_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_9.0.30729.6161_none_4bf7e3e2bf9ada4c.manifest
126971 INFO: Searching for file mfc90.dll
126971 INFO: Found file C:\Windows\WinSxS\x86_microsoft.vc90.mfc_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_9.0.30729.6161_none_4bf7e3e2bf9ada4c\mfc90.dll
126971 INFO: Searching for file mfc90u.dll
126971 INFO: Found file C:\Windows\WinSxS\x86_microsoft.vc90.mfc_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_9.0.30729.6161_none_4bf7e3e2bf9ada4c\mfc90u.dll
126971 INFO: Searching for file mfcm90.dll
126973 INFO: Found file C:\Windows\WinSxS\x86_microsoft.vc90.mfc_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_9.0.30729.6161_none_4bf7e3e2bf9ada4c\mfcm90.dll
126973 INFO: Searching for file mfcm90u.dll
126973 INFO: Found file C:\Windows\WinSxS\x86_microsoft.vc90.mfc_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_9.0.30729.6161_none_4bf7e3e2bf9ada4c\mfcm90u.dll
127069 INFO: Found C:\Windows\WinSxS\Manifests\x86_policy.9.0.microsoft.vc90.mfc_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_9.0.21022.8_none_5926f98ceadc42c2.manifest
127069 INFO: Found C:\Windows\WinSxS\Manifests\x86_policy.9.0.microsoft.vc90.mfc_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_9.0.30729.1_none_7dd1e0ebd6590e0b.manifest
127070 INFO: Found C:\Windows\WinSxS\Manifests\x86_policy.9.0.microsoft.vc90.mfc_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_9.0.30729.6161_none_ed01d9e4fb230e88.manifest
127072 INFO: Adding redirect Microsoft.VC90.MFC version (9, 0, 21022, 8) -> (9, 0, 30729, 6161)
130746 WARNING: Attempted to add Python module twice with different upper/lowercases: PyQt4.QtCore
130746 WARNING: Attempted to add Python module twice with different upper/lowercases: PyQt4.QtSvg
130746 WARNING: Attempted to add Python module twice with different upper/lowercases: PyQt4.QtGui
130746 WARNING: Attempted to add Python module twice with different upper/lowercases: OpenGL_accelerate.vbo
130746 WARNING: Attempted to add Python module twice with different upper/lowercases: OpenGL_accelerate.formathandler
130746 WARNING: Attempted to add Python module twice with different upper/lowercases: OpenGL_accelerate.arraydatatype
130746 WARNING: Attempted to add Python module twice with different upper/lowercases: OpenGL_accelerate.wrapper
130746 WARNING: Attempted to add Python module twice with different upper/lowercases: OpenGL_accelerate.latebind
130746 WARNING: Attempted to add Python module twice with different upper/lowercases: OpenGL_accelerate.errorchecker
130746 WARNING: Attempted to add Python module twice with different upper/lowercases: OpenGL_accelerate.numpy_formathandler
130746 WARNING: Attempted to add Python module twice with different upper/lowercases: OpenGL_accelerate.nones_formathandler
130746 WARNING: Attempted to add Python module twice with different upper/lowercases: OpenGL_accelerate.buffers_formathandler
130746 WARNING: Attempted to add Python module twice with different upper/lowercases: Crypto.Cipher._DES3
130746 WARNING: Attempted to add Python module twice with different upper/lowercases: Crypto.Util._counter
130746 WARNING: Attempted to add Python module twice with different upper/lowercases: Crypto.PublicKey._fastmath
130746 WARNING: Attempted to add Python module twice with different upper/lowercases: Crypto.Cipher._DES
130746 WARNING: Attempted to add Python module twice with different upper/lowercases: Crypto.Util.strxor
130746 WARNING: Attempted to add Python module twice with different upper/lowercases: Crypto.Hash._SHA256
130746 WARNING: Attempted to add Python module twice with different upper/lowercases: Crypto.Random.OSRNG.winrandom
130746 WARNING: Attempted to add Python module twice with different upper/lowercases: Crypto.Cipher._AES
130746 WARNING: Attempted to add Python module twice with different upper/lowercases: Crypto.Cipher._Blowfish
130746 WARNING: Attempted to add Python module twice with different upper/lowercases: Crypto.Cipher._ARC4
130746 WARNING: Attempted to add Python module twice with different upper/lowercases: PIL._webp
130746 WARNING: Attempted to add Python module twice with different upper/lowercases: PIL._imagingtk
130746 WARNING: Attempted to add Python module twice with different upper/lowercases: PIL._imaging
130746 WARNING: Attempted to add Python module twice with different upper/lowercases: PIL._imagingft
130746 WARNING: Attempted to add Python module twice with different upper/lowercases: scipy.optimize.moduleTNC
130746 WARNING: Attempted to add Python module twice with different upper/lowercases: Stemmer
130747 WARNING: Attempted to add Python module twice with different upper/lowercases: Cython.Compiler.Scanning
130747 WARNING: Attempted to add Python module twice with different upper/lowercases: Cython.Compiler.Parsing
130747 WARNING: Attempted to add Python module twice with different upper/lowercases: Cython.Compiler.Code
130747 WARNING: Attempted to add Python module twice with different upper/lowercases: Cython.Compiler.Visitor
130747 WARNING: Attempted to add Python module twice with different upper/lowercases: Cython.Compiler.FlowControl
130747 INFO: Looking for eggs
130747 INFO: Using Python library C:\Users\Public\MBELogAnalysis\python27.dll
130747 INFO: Found binding redirects: 
[BindingRedirect(name=u'Microsoft.VC90.MFC', language=None, arch=u'x86', oldVersion=(9, 0, 21022, 8), newVersion=(9, 0, 30729, 6161), publicKeyToken=u'1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b'), BindingRedirect(name=u'Microsoft.VC90.CRT', language=None, arch=u'x86', oldVersion=(9, 0, 21022, 8), newVersion=(9, 0, 30729, 6161), publicKeyToken=u'1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b')]
130848 INFO: Warnings written to C:\Users\Public\MBELogAnalysis\build\GetMBEPressure\warnGetMBEPressure.txt
132418 INFO: checking PYZ
132418 INFO: Building PYZ because out00-PYZ.toc is non existent
132418 INFO: Building PYZ (ZlibArchive) C:\Users\Public\MBELogAnalysis\build\GetMBEPressure\out00-PYZ.pyz
136802 INFO: checking PKG
136802 INFO: Building PKG because out00-PKG.toc is non existent
136802 INFO: Building PKG (CArchive) out00-PKG.pkg
138115 INFO: Redirecting Microsoft.VC90.CRT version (9, 0, 21022, 8) -> (9, 0, 30729, 6161)
175003 INFO: Bootloader c:\python27\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\bootloader\Windows-32bit\run_d.exe
175003 INFO: checking EXE
175003 INFO: Building EXE because out00-EXE.toc is non existent
175003 INFO: Building EXE from out00-EXE.toc
175006 INFO: Appending archive to EXE C:\Users\Public\MBELogAnalysis\dist\GetMBEPressure.exe
```

When I run the exe it gives me the output:

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601]
Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

C:\Users\Public\MBELogAnalysis\dist>GetMBEPressure
PyInstaller Bootloader 3.x
LOADER: executable is C:\Users\Public\MBELogAnalysis\dist\GetMBEPressure.exe
LOADER: homepath is C:\Users\Public\MBELogAnalysis\dist
LOADER: _MEIPASS2 is NULL
LOADER: archivename is C:\Users\Public\MBELogAnalysis\dist\GetMBEPressure.exe
LOADER: Extracting binaries
LOADER: Executing self as child
LOADER: set _MEIPASS2 to C:\Users\MARTIN~1\AppData\Local\Temp\_MEI76482
LOADER: Setting up to run child
LOADER: Creating child process
LOADER: Waiting for child process to finish...
PyInstaller Bootloader 3.x
LOADER: executable is C:\Users\Public\MBELogAnalysis\dist\GetMBEPressure.exe
LOADER: homepath is C:\Users\Public\MBELogAnalysis\dist
LOADER: _MEIPASS2 is C:\Users\MARTIN~1\AppData\Local\Temp\_MEI76482
LOADER: archivename is C:\Users\Public\MBELogAnalysis\dist\GetMBEPressure.exe
LOADER: SetDllDirectory(C:\Users\MARTIN~1\AppData\Local\Temp\_MEI76482)
LOADER: Already in the child - running user's code.
LOADER: manifestpath: C:\Users\MARTIN~1\AppData\Local\Temp\_MEI76482\GetMBEPress
ure.exe.manifest
LOADER: Activation context created
LOADER: Activation context activated
LOADER: Python library: C:\Users\MARTIN~1\AppData\Local\Temp\_MEI76482\python27.
dll
LOADER: Loaded functions from Python library.
LOADER: Manipulating environment (sys.path, sys.prefix)
LOADER: sys.prefix is C:\Users\MARTIN~1\AppData\Local\Temp\_MEI76~1
LOADER: Setting runtime options
LOADER: Bootloader option: pyi-windows-manifest-filename GetMBEPressure.exe.mani
fest
LOADER: Initializing python
LOADER: Overriding Python's sys.path
LOADER: Post-init sys.path is C:\Users\MARTIN~1\AppData\Local\Temp\_MEI76482
LOADER: Setting sys.argv
LOADER: setting sys._MEIPASS
LOADER: importing modules from CArchive
LOADER: extracted struct
LOADER: callfunction returned...
LOADER: extracted pyimod01_os_path
LOADER: callfunction returned...
LOADER: extracted pyimod02_archive
LOADER: callfunction returned...
LOADER: extracted pyimod03_importers
LOADER: callfunction returned...
LOADER: Installing PYZ archive with Python modules.
LOADER: PYZ archive: out00-PYZ.pyz
LOADER: Running pyiboot01_bootstrap.py
LOADER: Running pyi_rth_pkgres.py
LOADER: Running pyi_rth__tkinter.py
LOADER: Running pyi_rth_qt4plugins.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 43, in <module>
  File "c:\users\martin~1\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-arzhlv\pyinstaller\PyInst
aller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 546, in load_module
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified procedure could not be found.
pyi_rth_qt4plugins returned -1
LOADER: OK.
LOADER: Cleaning up Python interpreter.
LOADER: Back to parent (RC: -1)
LOADER: Doing cleanup
LOADER: Freeing archive status for C:\Users\Public\MBELogAnalysis\dist\GetMBEPre
ssure.exe
```

I have tried to google this problem and tried all sorts of solutions and modifications to the .spec file but nothing seems to work. A solution to a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29109324/pyinstaller-and-pandas) also did not work for me. Either I get the same error or new errors appear. Any help or advice on what I could try next would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Did you try with upx=False in the spec file? I get a similar error when UPX compression is on. It works when it's off.

Answer (score 0):

I had random issues with pyinstaller not importing things correctly until seeing several posts about grabbing the latest developer branch rather than using the latest release:
pip install https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/archive/develop.zip

Additionally, I ran into similar issues again when switching to a new development machine.  This time, the above solution didn't work.  Instead, it was a new issue similar to this https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/issues/1404
where a single dynamic library file was getting renamed to something the pyinstaller built exe didn't recognize.  In my case, my old machine produced a build with "libzmq.pyd" in the exe's directory, but the new machine instead had the file "zmq.libzmq.pyd".  I'm sure there's a better solution somewhere, but renaming that file back to "libzmq.pyd" did the trick, and the exe would run correctly on the new machine.  Any oddly named dynamic libraries in your build directory?