# Using pyinstaller with pandas

Tags: python, windows, pandas, pyinstaller

I'm attempting to use pyinstaller with pandas.  I wrote a very simple module:

installtest.py:

```
import pandas

print 'Hello!'
```

and then did:

```
pyinstaller .\installtest.py
```

Next I edited installtest.spec as explained in [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32974358/1572508), deleted the build and dist directories, and ran pyinstaller again on the edited spec:

```
pyinstaller .\installtest.spec
```

I then attempt to run the resulting exe like this:

```
.\dist\installtest\installtest.exe
```

However, I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "installtest.py", line 1, in <module>
    import pandas
  File "c:\users\admini~1\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-kuazog\pyinstaller\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", lin
e 389, in load_module
  File "site-packages\pandas\__init__.py", line 13, in <module>
ImportError: C extension: hashtable not built. If you want to import pandas from the source directory, you may need to r
un 'python setup.py build_ext --inplace' to build the C extensions first.
Failed to execute script installtest
```

It is apparently looking at site-packages\pandas__init__.py instead of anything in the dist folder.  Perhaps that is part of the issue?  I checked the dist folder, and it has the following pandas related files:

```
pandas._sparse.pyd
pandas._testing.pyd
pandas.algos.pyd
pandas.hashtable.pyd
pandas.index.pyd
pandas.json.pyd
pandas.lib.pyd
pandas.msgpack._packer.pyd
pandas.msgpack._unpacker.pyd
pandas.parser.pyd
pandas.tslib.pyd
```

Here is some system info:

- Python 2.7.11 :: Continuum Analytics, Inc.
- pandas version 0.17.0
- pyinstaller version 3.2
- Using Windows server 2012 R2 and Powershell

My question: how can I get this example working?

Comment: Have you solved the issue ?

Comment: @dylan_fan Unfortunately, I have not.  I ended up not using pyinstaller because of this and other difficulties, although I'm considering giving it another try soon.