# How do I fix this python converting file into an app - still have not found a solution

Tags: python, python-3.x, command-line, pyinstaller, oserror

This question is not a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25651990/oserror-winerror-193-1-is-not-a-valid-win32-application), because I am trying to create an *app*.

I am currently following [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UZX5kH72Yx4), but when I try to run my app,

my command prompt prints out this error:

[image]

Why does this error happen and how can I solve it? I read through all the answers to the [linked question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25651990/oserror-winerror-193-1-is-not-a-valid-win32-application), but none of them are pertinent to my problem.

Please anyone help me, I still haven't found a working solution; I am getting  desperate!!!

Edit: I can't just install and uninstall pynput? Idk why it doesn't work because shouldn't pynput come with idle?

Version: 3.74 python idle, most updated version of pyinstaller

Comment: Please edit your question to include the full error traceback

Comment: @JeffUK I just did:) Do you have any advice for me?

Comment: @Rebecca Bibye, When you run python myprogram.py and get an error, it means that your app is not able to run on your system. Before packaging it into an app, you need to fix it. From a traceback, it looks like there is a problem loading numpy library. Try reinstalling it. Let me know if you need help with that.

Comment: @George I reinstalled it, but it still doesn't work. Do you think it's because printing out a numpy table isn't compatible as an app and I'd have to format it first?

Comment: Could  you please try importing it in python shell, specifically 32bit ? 'import numpy' and see if it works. Chance is that numpy has libraries for 64 bit system, which won't work on 32bit

Comment: It worked! I don't know why, but it seriously worked. Could it maybe be that my app can't find a way to print out a numpy table so it prints out an error message instead?

Comment: Could you please elaborate on what exactly worked? I still think the problem was incompatible numpy libraries.

Comment: When I entered: 'import numpy' into the shell, it really imported it (no error message at all). Should that have happened?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226215/discussion-between-george-and-rebecca-bibye).

Comment: @RebeccaBibye what's your python and pyinstall version

Comment: I think [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63681770/getting-error-when-using-pynput-with-pyinstaller) might help you out.

Comment: I think [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63681770/getting-error-when-using-pynput-with-pyinstaller) will solve your problem!

Answer (score 1):

**The following might help you if you haven't tried them already:**

1. Update pip from the command line
2. Unistall pyinstaller
3. Re-install pyinstaller and try it again

If the above does not work, try running the following command in the command line. Make sure there are some print statements in your code to see if it works.

```
python monitoring_culmination_product.py
```

If you got a message saying "python is not recognised as an internal or external command" then python might have not been added as an environment path.Try [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sRRFgF4Us68) to fix the issue.
You could always re-install python if things get difficult.(make sure you install the appropriate version 32-64bit)

If the command though executed without a problem. Try to use pyinstaller on another file to see if the problem has to make sure the problem has to do with pyinstaller.
From a personal experience, pyinstaller can be unreliable at times so I put the following line in my projects just to make sure. It might help you too.

```
import pkg_resources.py2_warn
```

**Disclaimer:** Although it is not specified I assume that you are using Windows

Comment: I did what you said and it didn't work! here are some problems: when I ran "python myprogram.py" it got the same original error that I had above; it recognized python but it produced another error. When I tried to import pkg_resources.py2_warn, it said: ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pkg_resources. What should I do now?

Comment: @RebeccaBibye try this command `pyinstaller --hidden-import 'packaging.version' --hidden-import 'packaging.specifiers' --hidden-import 'packaging.requirements' --hidden-import 'pkg_resources.markers' myprogram.py`

Comment: I got the exact same error as my original command; OSError: [WinError 193] %1 is not a valid Win32 application        
Do you think it might be my program that is the problem or one of the packages inside the program rather than pyinstaller?

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use `conda create` to get an environment containing all the need dependencies (`numpy`, etc) and then use `pyinstaller` as explained in [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47769904/size-of-executable-using-pyinstaller-and-numpy).

Comment: I really don't want to install more stuff on my computer (like anaconda). Is there any other way?

Comment: You could probably use a venv,  [as explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48757977/how-to-include-dependencies-from-venv-directory-when-running-pyinstaller-for-pro).

Comment: I actually don't think I have pycharm either; I use idle version 3.74

Answer (score 0):

Please fall back to 1.6.8 version of pynput. pip install pynput==1.6.8

Ref : https://stackoverflow.com/a/63721929/14759065