# Why is the exe so big after pyinstaller?

Tags: python

I wrote a simple capital city quiz in python then complied it using pyinstaller and it is over 300MB! The code is below. Any ideas as to why it is so large!

Cheers,

Rich

```
import pandas as pd
from random import shuffle
from requests import post

difficulty=""
while difficulty.lower() != "easy" and difficulty.lower() != "hard":
    difficulty = input("Easy or Hard? ")
filename = "capitals_"+difficulty+".csv"

dataset = pd.read_csv(filename)
quiz_data = dataset.iloc[:, 0:2].astype(str).values.tolist()
shuffle(quiz_data)

name=""
while name.lower() != "beth" and name.lower() != "penny":
    name = input("Are you Beth or Penny? ")
webhooks_event=name + "Flash"




score=0
for n in range(10):
    ans=input(f"What is the capital city of {quiz_data[n][0]}? ")
    if ans.lower()==quiz_data[n][1].lower():
        print("Correct!")
        score+=1
    else:
        print(f"Sorry the correct answer was {quiz_data[n][1]}")

if score < 5:
    print(f"You need to do more studying! you got {score} out of 10!")
elif score <10:
    print(f"Well done you got {score} out of 10")
else:
    print("Excellent, you got them all right!")
    post(f"https://maker.ifttt.com/trigger/{webhooks_event}/with/key/#")
input("Press enter to continue")
```

Comment: I guess PyInstaller has to include all the modules you use (pandas, random and requests), and all the modules they use, and all the modules they use, etc...

Comment: PyInstaller  has issues with pandas https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29109324/pyinstaller-and-pandas

Comment: On the bright side, if Pandas is indeed the issue then you can quite easily rewrite the program without it. What do the contents of the CSV file look like?

Comment: Another possibly related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43886822/pyinstaller-with-pandas-creates-over-500-mb-exe/48846546#48846546

Comment: Python has a built-in CSV library (called `csv`) which will work in the vast majority of use-cases, and since it’s part of the standard library it won’t bloat your code like Pandas is. Give that a shot. requests shouldn’t be too expensive, I think, but it could also be replaced (less nicely) with urllib.

Comment: Thanks for the help, the data in the csv is very simple so I am sure I can use a simpler csv import method. Thanks for the help