# Import Error : C Extension while generating windows executable of a Python script using PyInstaller

Tags: windows, python-2.7, exe, pyinstaller

[image]Import error: C extension:  NO MODULE NAMED TIMEDELTAS NOT BUILT. If you want to import PANDAS from the source directory, you may need to run 'python setup.py build_ext --inplace' to build the C extensions first.

I tried following things up to now but couldn't resolve this :

- pip install --upgrade pip
- pip install --upgrade pandas
- uninstalled the existing version of pandas and installed again.
- pip install Cython

Please look at the SCREENSHOT ATTACHED ABOVE SHOWS VERSION of PANDAS, NUMPY, PYTZ, SIX installed on my system.

NOTE : I'm using Python 2.7

Any help on this will be appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47318119/no-module-named-pandas-libs-tslibs-timedeltas-in-pyinstaller