# python ImportError: C extension: No module named timedeltas not built

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

These days I want to use pyinstaller package my code into .exe file. After I run the .exe file tell me this problem.
So how do I solve this problem.
(I use python 2.7.14)
Thanks

[image: Img]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47318119/no-module-named-pandas-libs-tslibs-timedeltas-in-pyinstaller

Comment: Thanks, this problem I use other way solved

Comment: can you please post your solution.

Comment: @AhmadKarim I just go back to the original python site-package, copy and .py file paste to dist site-package folder and change name to the same format as the other file

Comment: Thanks!  I was manually trying to add packages because of no pip limitation on my embedded device and no install manager. I ended up copying the whole python2 folder from libraries or one working device to the other.