# pyinstaller error with scipy package

Tags: python, scipy, pyinstaller

I am trying to create an exe file with following command:

```
pyinstaller -F myfile.py
```

I was getting error on [No module named 'pandas._libs.tslibs.timedeltas' in PyInstaller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47318119/no-module-named-pandas-libs-tslibs-timedeltas-in-pyinstaller) and it got solved by creating a `hook-pandas.py` file with  following line in it as described on that page.

```
`hiddenimports = ['pandas._libs.tslibs.timedeltas']`
```

But now I am getting following error:

```
...
  File "site-packages\scipy\optimize\_trlib\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
  File "e:\0-anaconda\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 714, in load_module
    module = loader.load_module(fullname)
  File "messagestream.pxd", line 5, in init scipy.optimize._trlib._trlib
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'scipy._lib.messagestream'
[4380] Failed to execute script myfile
```

Following same pattern as above, I created another file named `hook-scipy.py` and put following line in it:

```
hiddenimports = ['scipy._lib.messagestream']
```

But the error has persisted. Where is the problem and how can it be solved?

(I am using python version 3.6.4 Anaconda and pyinstaller version 3.3.1 on Windows 7 operating system).

Comment: After creating `hook-scipy.py`, what command did you run to create `.exe` file? Have you specified `--additional-hooks-dir=` ?

Answer (score 1):

I recently had a similar issue and specifying:

```
hiddenimports=['scipy._lib.messagestream']
```

is not enough. I was able to get my issue, at least, to work when specifying:

```
hiddenimports=['scipy._lib.messagestream', 'scipy']
```

BTW this is for Python 3.6.1, PyInstaller 3.3.1 and scipy 1.2.1 on macOS.