# pyinstaller gives weird errors when compiling pandas

Tags: windows, python-3.x, pandas, pyinstaller

UPDATE june 18:

I would like compiling my python code for windows.
I use to work with pyinstaller, python 3.5+, windows 7 and anaconda to control modules pandas, pyqt (v5)  and pyqtgraph, but it seems something is not compatible. I would not be surprised if you tell me to change a version.

In previous versions, it worked with python 3.5, windows 7 and Pyinstaller 3.3.1- without pandas; the new version imports pandas and then this doesn’t work anymore:

- with the usual config pyinstaller gives a message saying the C libraries are not built. Following the instructions, I  should run `python setup.py build_ext --inplace --force`, except I don’t see the `setup.py` file, so I don’t know what to do. Forums tell me it should be a problem with pip but not with conda… but I use conda…
- with python 3.6, I got an error message ‘RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded’ (https://github.com/steph2016/profiles/blob/master/errorMessage). This problem seems known and solutions I found on forums is either to downgrade python or to replace my PyInstaller-3.3.1 by PyInstaller-3.4.dev0+7b3143612. But with PyInstaller-3.4.dev0+7b3143612 I get a ’’str’ object has no attribute ‘items’’ error (https://github.com/steph2016/profiles/blob/master/ErrorMessage2). I’m not sure pyinstaller is compatible with python 3.6…
- with python 3.4, I got an error similar to the ‘str object’ one above. I’m not sure python3.4 is compatible with qt5…

I would be pleased by any solution with any version of whatever to windows-compile my code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually applied the first solution proposed in [No module named 'pandas._libs.tslibs.timedeltas' in PyInstaller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47318119/no-module-named-pandas-libs-tslibs-timedeltas-in-pyinstaller) in the original config (python 3.5, PyInstaller 3.3.1, pyqtgraph, pandas, windows 7,...) and it worked.

I don't know why adding `def get_pandas_path ..... a.binaries)` helps, so I can't justify. But just to be explicit even if it seems obvious: pyinstaller must be run on the spec file, not on the py one (for instance `> pyinstaller toto.spec`)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it is the issue but I didn't find PyQtGraph in [Supported-Packages](https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/wiki/Supported-Packages)

Comment: indeed, it seems only recent versions of pyinstaller are compatible with pyqtgraph. but it is working with the previous release that uses pyqtgraph, the new problematic release uses pyqtgraph+pandas+others