# Failed to execute python script built using PyInstaller

Tags: python, anaconda, pyinstaller

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "site-packages\pandas\__init__.py", line 26, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\adas\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 631, in exec_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "site-packages\pandas\_libs\__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\adas\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 714, in load_module
    module = loader.load_module(fullname)
  File "pandas\_libs\tslibs\conversion.pxd", line 11, in init pandas._libs.tslib
  File "C:\Users\adas\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 714, in load_module
    module = loader.load_module(fullname)
  File "pandas\_libs\tslibs\conversion.pyx", line 1, in init pandas._libs.tslibs.conversion
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas._libs.tslibs.np_datetime'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "fetchall2.py", line 5, in <module>
    import pandas as pd
  File "C:\Users\adas\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 631, in exec_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "site-packages\pandas\__init__.py", line 35, in <module>
ImportError: C extension: No module named 'pandas._libs.tslibs.np_datetime' not built. If you want to import pandas from the source directory, you may need to run 'python setup.py build_ext --inplace --force' to build the C extensions first.
[283516] Failed to execute script fetchall2
```

I am trying to execute a python script i wrote. The script is supposed to create a PNG file based on the plot created by matplotlib. It works fine when I run it on the spyder IDE, but fails when I build it with PyInstaller.

using these imports

```
import MySQLdb
import numpy as np
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
matplotlib.use('Agg')
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.preprocessing import Imputer, LabelEncoder, OneHotEncoder, StandardScaler
from sklearn import svm
from sklearn.cross_validation import train_test_split
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
```

I tried to follow [Petr Szturc's Method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47318119/no-module-named-pandas-libs-tslibs-timedeltas-in-pyinstaller/47528057#47528057) and created a hooks-pandas.py file and with `hiddenimports = ['pandas._libs.tslibs.tslibs.np_datetime']` but continue to get the same traceback.

Anaconda 4.5.11

Python 3.6

Answer (score 0):

I think I've had same error in the past.

I have a `pyinstaller_hooks` directory in my project, and file `hook-pandas.py` with the following code:

```
from PyInstaller.utils.hooks import collect_submodules

hiddenimports = collect_submodules('pandas._libs.tslibs')
```

Then when running PyInstaller I pass the directory in the `--additional-hooks-dir`:

```
pyinstaller --additional-hooks-dir pyinstaller_hooks your_python_file.py
```

This makes it easy to identify what changes I have made for hooks, instead of mixing them into the PyInstaller folder, and they also are checked into any git repo. I think this is much cleaner than the method proposed in your link.

Comment: i solved it by updating the hidden-imports field in the spec file generated by pyinstaller. I had to do it multiple times since every time i added a "missing imports" it will tell me I am missing another import. After like 10 builds and adding 10 hidden-imports the executable worked. Also you have to run the program.spec in cmd for your specs to take effect or it will get overwritten with a blank spec file.