# Pandas exe window modification via spec file

Tags: python, pandas

I got an error in the pandas installation and hence have used the below solution:
[No module named 'pandas._libs.tslibs.timedeltas' in PyInstaller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47318119/no-module-named-pandas-libs-tslibs-timedeltas-in-pyinstaller?rq=1) .  Adding to the spec file.
But, I get the exe window worked only if the console is True and generates a black exe window along with my wanted exe window at the back which is not required. I want to hide the black exe window or delete it, by using the console True.
Because, when I tried using console False, then unfortunately it is not working.

I am pleased to hear some suggestions.