# Pyinstaller cannot find Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I use Pandas 0.20.3 and Pyinstaller 3.3.1 on anaconda, Windows7.
I create an executable but when I run it I get "no module named pandas" error. For testing, I also made a basic file as follows which yielded the same error when I created the exe file :

```
import pandas
print("x")
```

I followed the steps described in the 2 answers in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29109324/pyinstaller-and-pandas/32974358#32974358) but nothing has changed. My only doubt is regarding the sentence below which is a part of the the second answer in the thread:

> "I reinstalled pyinstaller manually via python setup.py install in the
>   Pyinstaller directory."

I am not sure if I got this but I just uninstalled and reinstalled pyinstaller via pip to replicate this.

Comment: `pandas` normally comes with anaconda pre-installed. What happens when you create a conda environment and install `pandas` there?

Comment: It is installed without any problem. The pandas module constitutes a big deal of my code and it works as expected.

Comment: Is your problem solved then? or are you still having this issue?

Comment: Unfortunately not. Actually I always had the module. The problem is when I make the executable. I click the exe file and it says "no module named pandas" but it is there.

Comment: Which version of PyInstaller did you use?

Comment: pyinstaller: 3.3.1 pandas: 0.21.1 python 3.4

Answer (score 0):

So it turns out the problem was related to having Anaconda installed. Once I uninstalled pandas from anaconda the answer of physicistintheory in this [discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29109324/pyinstaller-and-pandas/32974358#32974358) worked.
Anaconda is a great tool but for this time I had to avoid it.

Comment: to be more precise it was the pandas installed in an anaconda directory that was the reason