# Pandas, Numpy in PyInstaller

Tags: python, pandas, pyinstaller

I have tried the mentioned solutions in [PyInstaller and Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29109324/pyinstaller-and-pandas). I am getting the error that importing numpy fails in pandas init method. Any ideas how to solve this? Numpy 1.6.0 Pandas 0.24.0 Pyinstaller 3.4 Python 3.7

```
File "lib\site-packages\pandas\__init__.py", line 19, in <module>
ImportError: Missing required dependencies ['numpy']
```

There is already a hook-pandas as well as a hook-numpy python file in ../PyInstaller/hooks/.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Numpy 1.6.1 just got released and did the trick for me. Somehow 1.6.0 caused problems for PyInstaller.

Answer (score 1):

I upgraded pyinstaller and fixed the issue for me