# Pandas and pyinstaller

Tags: python, pandas, pyinstaller

I want to convert my python script to exe file using pyinstaller. My python script have pandas library. How to deploy pandas library using pyinstaller. I have tried modifying the spec file as mentioned in [PyInstaller and Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29109324/pyinstaller-and-pandas). But I'm getting following error when converting the file.

[image: Error image]

The spec file I used.

```
# -*- mode: python -*-

block_cipher = None

def get_pandas_path():
    import pandas
    pandas_path = pandas.__path__[0]
    return pandas_path

a = Analysis(['test.py'],
         pathex=['D:\\test.py'],
         binaries=None,
         datas=None,
         hiddenimports=[],
         hookspath=None,
         runtime_hooks=None,
         excludes=None,
         win_no_prefer_redirects=None,
         win_private_assemblies=None,
         cipher=block_cipher)

dict_tree = Tree(get_pandas_path(), prefix='pandas', excludes=["*.pyc"])
a.datas += dict_tree
a.binaries = filter(lambda x: 'pandas' not in x[0], a.binaries)

pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data,
         cipher=block_cipher)
exe = EXE(pyz,
      a.scripts,
      exclude_binaries=True,
      name='test',
      debug=False,
      strip=None,
      upx=True,
      console=True )
scoll = COLLECT(exe,
           a.binaries,
           a.zipfiles,
           a.datas,
           strip=None,
           upx=True,
           name='test')
```

Can anyone help me where I'm wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I tried uninstalling pandas and installing again. Now it is working.