# Pynistaller .exe does not seem to embeded Python

Tags: python, windows, pyinstaller

I created an `.exe` file with pyinstaller on Windows but when I try to open it on another Windows computer I have a traceback.

To create the .exe, I installed Python 3.7.

Then I pip installed pyinstaller and run it with `--onefile`:

```
PS> py -3.7 -m pip install pyinstaller 
PS> pyinstaller --onefile hello_world.py
```

I expect that `pyinstaller --onefile`

- embeded in the exe file everything including the Python.
- On the traceback I see that the python interpreter is the
  `c:\users\helen\appdata\local\programs\python\python37` this is the Python I used to create the `.exe`. This Python is not suppose to exist in the target Windowe I execute the `.exe`

My goal is to make this .exe work on any computer.

Am I missing something ? Are there other arguments for pyinstaller to prevent those kinds of errors ?

### important note: this is not a question relate to including pandas in  pyinstaller [PyInstaller and Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29109324/pyinstaller-and-pandas)

### `hello_world.py`

My hello_world.py is just a simple script using Tkinter to print hello world.

```
import tkinter as tk
import pandas as pd

class Application(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        super().__init__(master)
        self.master = master
        self.master.geometry("250x50")
        self.master.title("POC")
        self.pack()
        self.create_widgets()

    def create_widgets(self):
        self.hi_there = tk.Label(self)
        self.hi_there["text"] = "Hello World"
        self.hi_there.pack(fill='x', side="top")
        self.quit = tk.Button(self, text="QUIT", fg="red",
                              command=self.master.destroy)
        self.quit.pack(side="bottom")


root = tk.Tk()
app = Application(master=root)
app.mainloop()
```

### traceback

```
[7728] Failed to execute script hello_world

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "hello_world.py", line 2, in <module>

  File "c:\users\helen\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 493, in exec_module

  File "pandas\__init__.py", line 55, in <module>

  File "c:\users\helen\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 493, in exec_module

  File "pandas\core\api.py", line 29, in <module>

  File "c:\users\helen\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 493, in exec_module

  File "pandas\core\groupby\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>

  File "c:\users\helen\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 493, in exec_module

  File "pandas\core\groupby\generic.py", line 60, in <module>

  File "c:\users\helen\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 493, in exec_module

  File "pandas\core\frame.py", line 124, in <module>

  File "c:\users\helen\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 493, in exec_module

  File "pandas\core\series.py", line 4572, in <module>

  File "pandas\core\generic.py", line 10349, in _add_series_or_dataframe_operations

  File "c:\users\helen\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 493, in exec_module

  File "pandas\core\window\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>

  File "c:\users\helen\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 493, in exec_module

  File "pandas\core\window\ewm.py", line 5, in <module>

ImportError: DLL load failed: Le module spécifié est introuvable.
```