# Python Pycryptodome issue

Tags: python

Hello anyone reading this, I'm new to python and I am  trying out a program which uses pycryptodome to decipher some code. Every time I open the program it gives out the error message below.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python File Folder\SX_License.py", line 8, in <module>
    from Crypto.Cipher import AES
  File "C:\Users\MyUser\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\Crypto\Cipher\__init__.py", line 27, in <module>
    from Crypto.Cipher._mode_ecb import _create_ecb_cipher
  File "C:\Users\MyUser\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\Crypto\Cipher\_mode_ecb.py", line 35, in <module>
    raw_ecb_lib = load_pycryptodome_raw_lib("Crypto.Cipher._raw_ecb", """
  File "C:\Users\MyUser\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\Crypto\Util\_raw_api.py", line 309, in load_pycryptodome_raw_lib
    raise OSError("Cannot load native module '%s': %s" % (name, ", ".join(attempts)))
OSError: Cannot load native module 'Crypto.Cipher._raw_ecb': Not found '_raw_ecb.cp39-win_amd64.pyd', Not found '_raw_ecb.pyd
```

Thank you for reading this.

Comment: https://github.com/Legrandin/pycryptodome/issues/155

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to build executable with pyinstaller that uses pycryptodome?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46584140/how-to-build-executable-with-pyinstaller-that-uses-pycryptodome)