# PyInstaller - Program returns -1 in another computer

Tags: python, windows, import, exe, pyinstaller

I am using PyInstaller to compile my program to an .exe in Windows,

I use the normal line: *pyinstaller file.py --onefile*

And all looks like working, while executing PyInstaller says about a WARNING but still "Succesfull finished".

So then i execute my program file.exe and it works perfectly.

The surprise comes when i go to another computer and try to run it...
It start running but when it achieves a point it returns:

**Traceback**: *TypeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '**getitem**' files returned -1*

Warnings of compilations are:

*missing module named 'Carbon.File'.FSGetResourceForkName - imported by 'Carbon.File', plistlib
missing module named 'Carbon.File'.FSRef - imported by 'Carbon.File', plistlib*

...170 more...

Well, so now comes the question and sorry about the "long" post:

1. **I am not using** Carbon,math.cos,etc,etc (From Warning files) in my program I even dont know what Carbon is, it is "imported by ...", how can I do this **to dont be imported so it will work in all computers**.
2. If my program works in my computer but not in other I guess I am leaving out something to import?
3. I have seek for answer and ofc there are but what I have found are really specific: Example: [pyInstaller: Import Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15114695/pyinstaller-import-error) What to do when your imports are missing 170 modules?

Thanks!

**Edit:**

Full Traceback:

[image: Full Traceback]

Code:

```
def check_actived (connection):
sql_query = """SELECT enabled FROM login """
connection.execute(sql_query)
result = connection.fetchone()
return result[0]
```

Comment: Please post the whole traceback and the code which causes the traceback. Is this your code or imported code? Currently you should relax on the pyinstaller warnings.

Comment: @kotletschabowy hi, thanks for answering I have edited the main post.