# Pyinstaller Wildcard Import

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyinstaller

I have this piece of code

```
from module1 import *

feature1() # from module1
```

I get a `NameError` exception

```
NameError: global name 'feature1' is not defined
```

It works perfectly in `python main.py`, but when I use `pyinstaller` to compile, my executable throws the `NameError` exception. How would I go about fixing this?

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure that module1 exists and defined
2. Make sure that feature1 exists in module1
3. Make sure that feature1 is a function, not anything else (like type or object)
4. If you use a virtual environment, make sure that the package is installed there and

4a. Make sure that you run your script from the virtual environment

Comment: All features and modules exist and properly typed. It also works in `virtualenv`, but not with `pyinstaller`.

Comment: @AidanH Have you checked this topic https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15114695/pyinstaller-import-error ?

Comment: I have checked it out, and I an able to import `module1` but I am unable to access the feature within.

Comment: @AidanH Which version of Python do you use?

Comment: @AidanH I saw many people struggle with Python 3.7 and many found using 3.5 more successful. Maybe you would try this version?

Comment: I will check it out.

Answer (score 0):

You really shouldn't use `import *` it makes it so much harder to work out where objects come from - any many linters will simply not work.

Try doing:

```
from module1 import *
dir()
```

this will tell you what has been imported and is available to use. If `feature1` isn't there then you have your explanation - if it is there you have a more complex journey ahead of you.

Comment: `feature1` does show when in Python, but I don't believe it is being imported into my pyinstaller executable.

Answer (score 0):

When compiling your script with pyinstaller, use the command `pyinstaller -p /Path/To/Your/Module1/Folder main.py`

This will add the directory containing your scripts to the PATH variable and will add your module1.py to the compiled exe.