# How do I handle custom modules when creating an exe with PyInstaller?

Tags: python-3.x, pyinstaller, executable, python-module

Using PyInstaller I created a executable from a python script as follows:

```
pyinstaller --onefile pythonScriptName.py
```

However, when I run the executable I get an error `ImportError: No module named 'MyModule'`.
'MyModule' is a placeholder name for a custom module I use in the script. So I'm assuming that PyInstaller didn't package up the custom modules. Is there some way to get it to do that?

Comment: Where is you custom module located ? If it's being imported in `pythonScriptName.py`, then you can tell pyinstaller to search for it in any additional folders using `--paths "/location/of/folder"`. If it's not visible through any import statement, you could also use `--hidden-import modulename` along with this...

Comment: This discussion says the same things too https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15114695/imported-module-not-found-in-pyinstaller  The question is for windows, but these flags aren't platform specific and have worked for me on macOS as well

Answer (score 1):

I found the `--collect-submodules` flag to be helpful when getting an import module error.
I just specify the folder name under which all my modules are and pyinstaller collects all the imports automatically.
something like this:

```
pyinstaller --collect-submodules <folder-name>
```