# Is there any way to fix "no module named matplotlib"

Tags: python, matplotlib, pyinstaller

I create a file and it includes `matplotlib` so when I convert it to exe it throws an error. How can I solve this problem? It says *no module named matplotlib*. How can I add module? How can I remove this error?

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import tkinter as tk
root=tk.Tk()
kazanım1yanlıssayısı=int(input('number'))
kazanım1bossayısı=int(input('number'))
kazanım1dogrusayısı=int(input('number'))


def buttoncall():
    slices = [kazanım1bossayısı, kazanım1dogrusayısı]
    cols = ['blue', 'green']
    dyb = ['Boş', 'Doğru']
    dyblist = list(dyb)

    plt.pie(slices, labels=dyb, colors=cols)
    plt.legend()

    plt.show()
    plt.close()


button = tk.Button(root, text='Graph', command=buttoncall)
button.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: conda install maptlotplib or pip intall matplotlib

Comment: You also have pyinstaller as a tag... so if you are trying to use it, check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73673886/3155240) by me and other answers on that page for help.

Comment: I convert it to exe but it says no module named matplotlib

Answer (score 2):

I using `pyinstaller v5.7.0` with `Python 3.10.8` on Windows 11 Pro.

No ask `no module named matplotlib`

I think you needs to install latest `pyinstaller` and Python 3.10.x version.

This my steps.

Version check on Command Prompt

```
>python --version
Python 3.10.8

>pyinstaller --version
5.7.0

>pip --version
pip 22.3.1 from D:\DevTools\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pip (python 3.10)
```

Code save as `data.py`

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import tkinter as tk
root=tk.Tk()
kazanım1yanlıssayısı=int(input('number'))
kazanım1bossayısı=int(input('number'))
kazanım1dogrusayısı=int(input('number'))


def buttoncall():
    slices = [kazanım1bossayısı, kazanım1dogrusayısı]
    cols = ['blue', 'green']
    dyb = ['Boş', 'Doğru']
    dyblist = list(dyb)

    plt.pie(slices, labels=dyb, colors=cols)
    plt.legend()

    plt.show()
    plt.close()


button = tk.Button(root, text='Graph', command=buttoncall)
button.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Install library

```
pip install matplotlib
pip install pyinstaller
```

Create Executable by `pyinstaller`

```
pyinstaller --onefile data.py
```

Show logs of `pyinstaller` in terminal

```
>pyinstaller --onefile data.py
218 INFO: PyInstaller: 5.7.0
219 INFO: Python: 3.10.8
254 INFO: Platform: Windows-10-10.0.22000-SP0
254 INFO: wrote D:\temp\answer188\data.spec
260 INFO: UPX is not available.
263 INFO: Extending PYTHONPATH with paths
...
...
37542 INFO: Updating resource type 24 name 1 language 0
37552 INFO: Appending PKG archive to EXE
37582 INFO: Fixing EXE headers
38149 INFO: Building EXE from EXE-00.toc completed successfully.
```

Created files

```
>tree /F
Folder PATH listing for volume DATA
Volume serial number is 16D6-338C
D:.
│   data.py
│   data.spec
│
├───build
│   └───data
│       │   Analysis-00.toc
│       │   base_library.zip
│       │   data.exe.manifest
│       │   data.pkg
│       │   EXE-00.toc
│       │   PKG-00.toc
│       │   PYZ-00.pyz
│       │   PYZ-00.toc
│       │   Tree-00.toc
│       │   Tree-01.toc
│       │   Tree-02.toc
│       │   warn-data.txt
│       │   xref-data.html
│       │
│       └───localpycs
│               pyimod01_archive.pyc
│               pyimod02_importers.pyc
│               pyimod03_ctypes.pyc
│               pyimod04_pywin32.pyc
│               struct.pyc
│
└───dist
        data.exe
```

Run it `./dist/data.exe`

[image]

It shows Pie chart without problem.
[image]

If you want to copy to USB, just copy `data.exe`.
(without any other files copy)
Then run it by clicking from `explorer` , it works

[image]

Comment: Can i copy this to a usb easily?

Comment: @JuniorMehmet, I test it to copy to USB and run it. It works, I updated my answer at the end of part.

Comment: I dont understand down of the created files what is this?

Comment: @JuniorMehmet, After execute the command `pyinstaller -F your-file.py` Finally, go to the dist directory and get the executable file `your-file.exe`. That file is created into `dist` directory. Other files for building to help file under `build` directory.